# Using variables eats my data points

Tags: r, statistics

Doing a statistics assignment (regarding paternity testing) and thought I'd use R to help out with it. Basically what I'm doing at this point is trying to parse various allele frequencies and compute the likelihood ratios of the hypotheses *Alleged Father* is actually *Father* and *No Relation*.

Here's my code:

```
#Reading data
data.D1S80 = as.data.frame(read.table('Locus D1S80.txt'))
names(data.D1S80) = c("alleles", "counts")
#Getting empirical frequencies
pD1S80<-data.D1S80$counts/sum(data.D1S80$counts)
#Calculating the genotype probabilities under H(AF)
n<-length(pD1S80)
probHAF <-numeric (0)
for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:n){
    for (k in 1:n){
      valueAF = 0
      if ((i==j)&(j==k)) {
        valueAF = pD1S80[i]^3
      } else if ((i==j)&(k!=i)) {
        valueAF = (pD1S80[i]^2)*pD1S80[k]
      } else if ((i!=j)&(k!=j)&(k!=i)) {
        valueAF = pD1S80[i]*pD1S80[j]*pD1S80[k] 
      } else if ((i=!j)&(j==k)&(i<j)) {
        valueAF = pD1S80[i]*pD1S80[j]*(pD1S80[i]+pD1S80[j])
      } else if ((i==k)&(i!=j)) {
        valueAF = pD1S80[j]*pD1S80[i]^2
      } 
      probHAF <-c(probHAF, valueAF)
    }
  }
}
```

So basically I'm trying to find the empirical allele frequencies here by combining the expressions. This expression should sum to one. The dataset has 27 points and three variables, so I'm expecting a list on the order of `27^3 = 19683`. My code gives me `756`, which seems to be `27^2 + 27`. I have absolutely no idea where that's coming from.

The problematic bit is this one:

```
} else if ((i!=j)&(k!=j)&(k!=i)) {
  valueAF = pD1S80[i]*pD1S80[j]*pD1S80[k]
```

If I set the value to a constant, everything's fine (well, except that I get an incomplete distribution). Can someone help me out here? I am at my wit's end. I'm also pretty new to R, so I'd appreciate a detailed answer!

Many thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but for long chains of `if` and `else if`, you might find it more natural to use `switch` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid for loops here using `expand.grid` to generate all index at once. 
Then replace all the `if` and `else` by the vectorized `ifelse`. This is really faster and no need to allocate memory at begining.

For example, you first nested conditions can be rewritten like this:

```
pD1S80 <- round(rnorm(27),2)
id <- seq_along(pD1S80)
dat <- expand.grid(i=id,j=id,k=id)

valueAF <- with(dat,
     ifelse(i==j & j==k, pD1S80[i]^3,
            ifelse (i==j & k!=i,(pD1S80[i]^2)*pD1S80[k],
                                pD1S80[i]*pD1S80[j]*pD1S80[k] )))
```

**BENCHMARKING**

#### my vectorized solution is 70 times faster.

```
microbenchmark(ag(),op(),times=1)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
 ag()   31.52897   31.52897   31.52897   31.52897   31.52897     1
 op() 2181.76081 2181.76081 2181.76081 2181.76081 2181.76081     1
```

The functions used are:

```
pD1S80 <- round(rnorm(27),2)
ag <- function(){
  id <- seq_along(pD1S80)
  dat <- expand.grid(i=id,j=id,k=id)
  valueAF <- with(dat,
     ifelse(i==j & j==k, pD1S80[i]^3,
            ifelse (i==j & k!=i,(pD1S80[i]^2)*pD1S80[k],
                                0 )))
  valueAF
}

op <- function(){
  probHAF <- numeric (0)
n <- length(pD1S80)
for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:n){
    for (k in 1:n){
      valueAF = 0
      if ((i==j)&(j==k)) {
        valueAF = pD1S80[i]^3
      } else if ((i==j)&(k!=i)) {
        valueAF = (pD1S80[i]^2)*pD1S80[k]
      } 
      probHAF <-c(probHAF, valueAF)
    }}}
unlist(probHAF)
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this code, but it does seem to work better (read: at all, heh), so thanks!